# dynamically add tablerow with button and multiple edittext

Tags: android

How can I get the Ids for multiple Edit text which are created dynamically?

```
 public void onClick(View view) {              

            final TableRow row1 = new TableRow(Medication1.this);
            btn = new Button(Medication1.this);
            et1 = new EditText(Medication1.this);
            et2 = new EditText(Medication1.this);
            et3 = new EditText(Medication1.this);
            row1.addView(et1);
            row1.addView(et2);
            row1.addView(et3);
            row1.addView(btn);

            et2.setWidth(10);
            et1.setWidth(10);
            btn.setText("*");
            tableLayout.addView(row1);`
```

Comment: When you created a dynamic control, at that time Id is not possible to get, you can set Tag and get the Same Tag on runtime to handle UI control.

Answer (score 0):

to set an integer to view use this: `et1.setTag(1)`

to retrieve and compare use `et1.getTag()` somewhere later.

You can use lots of tags if you need:

`et1.setTag("STRINGKEY",value)`

`id` is xml specific value.